# What is an example of index usage in neo4j cypher 2.1.2 where clauses using the in operator?

Tags: neo4j

I our project we are constantly looking for ways to improve our cypher query speed. So when neo4j uses indexes in queries, we would like to use that advantage.
The new neo4j 2.1.2 release notes state:

"Cypher uses indexes for resolving WHERE clauses which use the IN operator"

But no further explanation is given. Can anyone give an example of such a query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
MATCH (a:User)-[:KNOWS]->()
WHERE a.userID IN [1, 2, 3, 4]
RETURN a
```

Assuming that "userID" is indexed, Neo4j will use that index when doing the comparisons using the "IN" operator in the WHERE clause.

HTH

Comment: +1, exactly, and strings will also work. id(a) IN [1,2,3,4] already worked as of 2.0.